# Mapping response to Model - best practise

Tags: javascript, json, angular, httpclient, observable

Getting up to speed with Angular 4, 5 here and was wondering whats best practice for mapping JSON response to a strong typed Object / Model.

Service:

```
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8000/users/')
    .pipe(
      tap(users => this.log(`fetched users`)),
      map(response => {
        return response.map((res) =>
        {
          return new Hero(
            response['username'],
            response.email);
        });
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError('getUsers', []))
    );
}
```

Interface / Model:

```
export interface IUser {

    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

export class Hero implements User {

    public id: number;

    constructor(public name: string,
            public email: string) {

  }
}
```

`getUsers` return an Observable Array with User Objects. `username` isnt a member of that Object so I use this bracket notation, since the dot notation gives an error. Obviously I eventually will take that Map function into a seperate function for testability/clarity.

How to handle this Mapping/Remapping/Transofmration properly?

Comment: you can directly typecast it to the interface as `return <IUser>response`

Comment: You mean `map(response => return <IHero>response)`, Then how does `username` map to `name`? Thats basically my question in this simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving yourself too much trouble.

```
export interface IUser {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
}

getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8000/users/')
    .catch(err => this.handleError('getUsers', []));
}
```

here you go, your response is typed.

See Typescript as a **developping help**. It's very useful to have classes and such during coding, but once you build your application, it's all compiled to Javascript, thus "losing" all classes and properties.

You shouldn't think too much for that. Just go for the simplest, and it should work. Otherwise, you still have a TS linter to tell you where your error is !

Comment: well this is quite a trivial example for something more complex coming up, being a RESTful API with different property names then on the FE. I understand and agree with you, however.. I am in search for this best practise implementation for mapping.

Comment: There's no "best practise implementation for mapping" : **you use mapping when you have to alter data**. If you need to map your response to fit your model on every call, then **change your model to cope with your response model**. Just type your call with `get<Type>`, and your function with `Observable<Type>`. Otherwise, you don't need to instanciate new elements like you did. That's wasting time, resources, and lines of code.